# user not found or not unique SharePoint 2013 with Reporting Service SSRS 2014

Tags: c#, sharepoint, reporting-services

I have SharePoint 2013 Web Application with on Form Based Authentication, and SSRS.

I tried to run report (.rdl) alone from browser with the user ID (from aspnet_users) table it's work, but from code it's not work and gave me "The user does not exist or is not unique"

I passed parameter using

`List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("UserId", Userid, false));
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);`
 
Any Help?

Comment: can you clarify more information. how you are trying to access the report, are you trying to pass the user name or the user id. you need to explain more..

Comment: I have report server in SharePoint _vti_bin/reportserver and I have list of type reports inside SharePoint site, then from webpart I added reportviewer.webform that open the report dynamically from code behind as I mentioned in code